# How did the inner loop execute "n/i" times?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have a doubt regarding the time complexity of a code snippet and didn't quite understand the solution given.

```
function (n) {
           for(int i =0 ; i < n ; i ++){
                       for(int j = 0 ; j <= n ; j += i){
                                  printf("*");
                                      }
```

In the above code, it's given that inner loop executes `n/i` times for each value of `i` . And , overall time complexity is `O(nlogn)`.

I can't figure out why the inner loop executes `n/i` times. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? The inner loop variable (`j`) is being incremented by `i`, but on the first loop, `i` is zero, and so `j` will never change, and that loop will never terminate.

Comment: `j` will change as `j` is incrementing and the inner loop terminates when `j > n`. The above code is correct.

Comment: If you look at the code, you will see that `j` is **not** being incremented. The expression `j += i` adds `0` to `j` for the first iteration of the outer loop (`i` is intialised as `i = 0`). `j` will never change, and the loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two loops, one incrementing `i`, and one incrementing `j`.

Given fixed `i`, for each pass of the `j` loop, `j` increments by `i`, until `j` reaches `n`.

So the values of `j` in each iteration are:

```
j
j + i
j + 2i
...
j + (n/i - j/i)i
```

As you can see, this runs O(n/i) times.

Comment: Thanks alot that clarified the doubt.

Comment: But I have a doubt. Why can't the final iteration be `j+ni` ? Then it runs O(n) times.